# How to get chrome extension ID in dev and production?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I work on a chrome extension.

I do use some messages between my web page and background process.

Problem is: the ID of my application is different when it comes from the google extension page and the one I locally work on and debugging.

Is there a way to make both ID same so debug and production version can communicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it in the webstore developer dashboard. Click the more info button. Copy the "Public key". Add a "key" item to manifest.json. Paste the string value to key. Like this: `"key": "yourPublicKey"`